# how to bind a combobox automatically when Customer is entered in CustomerEntry form

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

In my project i am having two forms BillEntry and CustomerEntry.

In CustomerEntry new customers are added.

[image: BillEntry form Combobox]

Here when new button is pressed i am opening a new form of CustomerEntry, here BillEntry form is already open at the back of the CustomerEntry form. I dont want my BillEntry form to close..

Here the Customer combobox will not take the new customer entered in customerentry..

I am binding the customer combobox in the constructor of the BillEntry form with LINQ...

And binding combobox on combobox enter event is also not working..

Please show me the way how can i do it...

linq query or the code is not the problem.
the problem is where can i call the binding method which binds the combobox?

```
public BillEntry()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      Customer_Binding();           
}

private void Customer_Binding()
{
      DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
      cbx_customer.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
      cbx_customer.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
      cbx_customer.DataSource = db.Customers;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us what your LINQ query is returning, and how you are binding it to the combo box at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BindingSources might then be better.

Add a BindingSource to your form, then in the properties of the comboBox set the DataSource property to the bindingSource you just added.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Then you set the data source of the BindingSource to your Customers list:

e.g. something like

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = customers;

//you still need to tell the combo box what to show
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SomeText"; 
comboBox1.ValueMember = "SomeValue";
```

Then when you add new data to your Customers list, just call:

```
bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

When binding to strings, it's usually as straightforward as:

```
List<string> items = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

But if you're using objects, it might be slightly trickier:

Given an object, "TestObject"

```
public class TestObject
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

You bind to it like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new List<TestObject> 
{ 
    new TestObject { SomeText = "One", SomeValue = 1 },
    new TestObject { SomeText = "Two", SomeValue = 2 },
    new TestObject { SomeText = "Three", SomeValue = 3 }
};
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SomeText";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "SomeValue";
```

"DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" are the property **names** of the object that you wish to display and use as values respectively.

Comment: I already know binding...
I want to automatically rebind it when a customer is added..

Comment: BindingSources might be a better option then. See my second answer.